# Yii2 codeception dataFile fixture can't be found

Tags: yii2, codeception

I am trying to run simple test and insert two record in db via fixture dataFile.
What I get is :

```
[ReflectionException] Class C:\xampp\htdocs\codeception\frontend\tests/_data\user.php does not exist
```

The file is obviously there. My `UserTest.php` looks like this:

```
<?php

class UserTest extends \Codeception\Test\Unit
{
    public function _fixtures()
    {
        return [
            'class' => \frontend\tests\fixtures\UserFixture::className(),
            'dataFile' => codecept_data_dir() . 'user.php'
        ];
    }

    public function testValidation()
    {
        $user = new \common\models\User();

        $user->setUsername(null);
        $this->assertFalse($user->validate(['username']));

        $user->setUsername('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa');
        $this->assertFalse($user->validate(['username']));

        $user->setUsername('toma');
        $this->assertTrue($user->validate(['username']));
    }

    public function testIfUserExist()
    {
        $this->tester->seeRecord('user', ['name' => 'Toma']);
    }
}
```

I saw the linux like forward slash in the error but don't know how to change it. Not sure if this is the problem because I had the same path with some images and it was fine then. What can cause this ? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You're using [`seeRecord()`](https://codeception.com/docs/modules/Yii2#seeRecord) in a wrong way. First argument needs to by class name, including namespace, so you should use it like this:

```
$this->tester->seeRecord(\frontend\models\User::class, ['name' => 'Toma']);
```

Comment: Oh. Thank you! I didnt read right I guess :) Will try later if that was the whole problem and will give a feedback.